# How change html template of ImageField in edit form?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-widget, django-1.11

I use **Django 1.11** in my project. In my edit form I have **ImageField**. Django by default render html which you can see below. How change html of ImageField in edit form correctly?

I tried next code but Django raise error *TemplateDoesNotExist*. Django dont see *template_file* in my custom widget? How to fix this problem? By the way *initial_text* and *input_text* works well. Also I tried *template_with_initial* but unfortunately it didnt help me. I would be grateful for any help!

Django render this **html by default**:

```
Currently:
<a href="/media/images/2017/08/23/picture.jpg">images/2017/08/23/picture.jpg</a>
Change:
<input name="image" id="id_image" type="file">
```

**widgets.py:**

```
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput

class CustomClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
    initial_text = 'Current image'

    input_text = 'Change'

    clear_checkbox_label = 'Clear Image'

    template_name = 'custom_clearable_file_input.html' <-- DONT WORK
```

**custom_clearable_file_input.html:**

```
{% if widget.is_initial %}
  <span>{{ widget.initial_text }}</span>: <a href="{{ widget.value.url }}">{{ widget.value }}</a>
  {% if not widget.required %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ widget.checkbox_name }}" id="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}"/>
    <label for="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}">{{ widget.clear_checkbox_label }}</label>
  {% endif %}
  <br/>
  <span>{{ widget.input_text }}</span>:
{% endif %}
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}/>
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nurzhan/CA/article/views.py", line 106, in get
    request=request
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 68, in render
    reraise(exc, self.backend)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 89, in reraise
    six.reraise(exc.__class__, new, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 993, in render
    bits.append(force_text(bit))
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 76, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 385, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 41, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 120, in as_widget
    **kwargs
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 221, in render
    return self._render(self.template_name, context, renderer)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 226, in _render
    return mark_safe(renderer.render(template_name, context))
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/renderers.py", line 31, in render
    template = self.get_template(template_name)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/renderers.py", line 37, in get_template
    return self.engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 41, in get_template
    reraise(exc, self)
  File "/srv/envs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 89, in reraise
    six.reraise(exc.__class__, new, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/srv/envs/kaseAdmPy362/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/envs/kaseAdmPy362/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 39, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "/srv/envs/kaseAdmPy362/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 162, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "/srv/envs/kaseAdmPy362/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/engine.py", line 148, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name, tried=tried)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: custom_clearable_file_input.html
[24/Aug/2017 11:02:30] "GET /administration/article/47/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends from the path where your custom template file is stored.

As described in the [form rendering documentations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/):

> Django’s form widgets are rendered using Django’s template engines system.
>
> The rendering of form templates is controlled by ... DjangoTemplates
>   [renderer class].
>
> [DjangoTemplates] renderer uses a standalone DjangoTemplates engine
>   (unconnected to what you might have configured in the TEMPLATES
>   setting). It loads templates first from the built-in form templates
>   directory in django/forms/templates and then from the installed apps’
>   templates directories using the app_directories loader.
>
> If you want to render templates with customizations from your
>   TEMPLATES setting, such as context processors for example, use the
>   TemplatesSetting renderer.

You have two options:

1. Create a `templates` sub-directory inside your (app_name) folder and put your temmplate file in this folder. (`/app_name/templates/custom_clearable_file_input.html`)
2. you can leave your template file in the global `templates` folder specified in your `TEMPLATES['DIRS']` parameter of your `settings.py` file (`/templates/custom_clearable_file_input.html`) but you have to use TemplatesSetting renderer as specified in the [TemplatesSettings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/#templatessetting) ( I added an example of customization for the `settings.py` file )

   ```
   import django
   ...
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       ...
       'django.forms'
       ...
   ]
   ...
   TEMPLATES = [
       {
           ...
           'DIRS': [
               'templates',
               django.__path__[0] + '/forms/templates',
           ],
           'APP_DIRS': True,

           ...
       },
   ]
   ...
   FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
   ```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. I store my custom template in "templates" folder which is in top level of my project. In settings.py I wrote the path to my 'templates' folder. Can you show me little example pls. I am little bit comfused.

Comment: My custom widget file is inside (app_name) folder. PATH: `app_name>widgets.py`.

Comment: I updated my answer with documentation quotes and examples of path.

Comment: Thank you! Your first option works well! But I want to try the second one cause I think its would be better to store all templates in one folder, in one place. In my `settings.py` file I specified next code for `TEMPLATES`: `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],`. I am little bit comfused with `TemplatesSetting`. or to be more precise with settings. What kind of settings I need to add?

Comment: What's not clear in the second documentation links I posted in my answer?

Comment: In that link, in `TemplatesSetting` I dont unserstand second part with code like `import django django.__path__[0] + '/forms/templates'`. What I need to write in that place?

Comment: I added an example of customization for the `settings.py`

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works! Can I ask one more question? Right now in my template (`custom_clearable_file_input.html`) `{% if widget.is_initial %}` dont work. How do you think why?

Comment: This is a specific template question I suggest to create a new question with all details relate to your template and your test.

Comment: I was hurried. Unfortunatly, 2-d option dont work. I wrote `django.__path__[0] + 'templates',` but it raise error like: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: custom_clearable_file_input.html
`

Comment: You have to use `DIRS` list as specified in my example
`['templates', django.__path__[0] + '/forms/templates',]`

Comment: I did as you wrote. But it seems to me that path is not correct here: `django.__path__[0] + '/forms/templates',` I tried this path `/forms/templates`, `/templates/`, `/templates`, `templates`.

Comment: You need at list two values : `django.__path__[0] + '/forms/templates'` (default django widget template) and your custom path `templates` (if this folder is in the root of your projects, otherwise you you have to change this second path)

Comment: Well, finally I fount the solution. In `settings.py` you need to add this code:`FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'` and also add `'django.forms', `in `INSTALLED_APPS`. After that widget works. Thats all. Thank you for your advices and help! Have a nice day! =)

Comment: 'djanfo.forms' was already in my example, now I've added also `FORM_RENDER`